Django Error: DisallowedHost - Invalid HTTP_HOST header when using custom domain from Namecheap
I recently deployed a Django application on AWS EC2 and successfully accessed it via its public IP. I then purchased a domain from Namecheap (www.myproject.com) to use instead of the IP address. After configuring the domain, I encountered the following error when running Gunicorn with the command:
gunicorn –bind 127.0.0.1:8001 wsgi:application
Error traceback:
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.myproject.com,www.myproject.com'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://www.myproject.com,www.myproject.com/
Django Version:
5.1.1
Exception Type:
DisallowedHost
Exception Value:
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.myproject.com,www.myproject.com'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
Exception Location:
/home/ubuntu/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/http/request.py, line 151, in get_host
Raised during:
transcribe_audio.views.index
Python Executable:
/home/ubuntu/myproject/.venv/bin/python3
Python Version:
3.12.3
Python Path:
['/home/ubuntu/myproject/e',
 '/home/ubuntu/myproject/.venv/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python312.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.12',
 '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ubuntu/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
 '/home/ubuntu/myproject']
Server time:
Sun, 13 Oct 2024 13:37:50 +0000


From the error, it looks like the HTTP_HOST header is somehow being duplicated (www.myproject.com,www.myproject.com), which is causing the request to fail. I'm unsure why this duplication is happening and how to resolve it.
NGINX Configuration:
Here’s my NGINX config file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.com www.myproject.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /path/to/your/static/files;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}


Django settings.py:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myproject.com', 'www.myproject.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '1.21.3.14.1']

What I've Tried:
 Checked my NGINX configuration for any issues.
 Verified that the domain is properly configured on Namecheap with the correct DNS records.
 Ensured that the domain names in ALLOWED_HOSTS are correct.
Despite these efforts, the error persists, and I suspect it’s related to how the Host header is being handled in the NGINX proxy configuration.
Question:
What could be causing the HTTP_HOST header to contain a duplicated domain (i.e., www.myproject.com,www.myproject.com), and how can I fix this?

Duplicate Question, though it doesn't have a real answer.

The above "solution" says the bug was within the Django code.  So I suspect somewhere in your backend Django is already setting the HTTP_HOST header.

@LordElron I noticed from the thread you tagged with "Duplicate Question" is that I am also using CertBot and so did that OP.

try changing ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*] in your settings.py.  If the problem is with Django, then you will probably get a different error message.

Same error. My guess is that settings.py may not be where the error is.
